# How to create order programmatically in Magento 2 using custom module?

Tags: magento2, sales-order

**Following code helped me to create order in magento 2 and it is tested already using my magento api :**

*Include below classs in your module*

```
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use MageMoto\AdminAWB\Helper\AWBHelper;
use Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection;
use Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository
```

```
   public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request $request,
        OrderRepository $orderRepository,
        InvoiceService $invoiceService,
        InvoiceSender $invoiceSender,
        Transaction $transaction,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        QuoteFactory $quote,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        AWBHelper $dataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $product,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->invoiceService = $invoiceService;
        $this->transaction = $transaction;
        $this->invoiceSender = $invoiceSender;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->quote = $quote;
        $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }


    public function createMagentoOrder($orderData){
        $store=$this->_storeManager->getStore(5);
        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore(5)->getWebsiteId();
        $orderDetails=$this->_dataHelper->getShipRocketOrder($orderData['order_id']);
        $orderDetails=$orderDetails['data'];
        if(!isset($orderDetails['id'])){
            return;
        }
        
        $customer=$this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->loadByEmail($orderDetails['customer_email']);
        $name=explode(" ",$orderDetails['customer_name']);
        $region=$this->getRegionCode($orderDetails['customer_state']);
        $orderData['shipping_address']=[
            'firstname'    =>$name[0], 
            'lastname'     => $name[1], 
            'street' => $orderDetails['customer_address'],
            'city' => $orderDetails['customer_city'],
            'country_id' => 'IN',
            'region_id'=> $region['region_id'],
            'postcode' => $orderDetails['customer_pincode'],
            'telephone' => $orderDetails['customer_phone'],
            'save_in_address_book' => 1
                 ];
         
        if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
            //If not avilable then create this customer 
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->setStore($store)
                    ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
                    ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
                    ->setEmail($orderDetails['customer_email']) 
                    ->setPassword($orderDetails['customer_email']);
            $customer->save();
        }

        
        $quote=$this->quote->create(); 
        $quote->setStore($store); 
        $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
 
        //add items in quote
        foreach($orderDetails['products'] as $item){
            $product=$this->_product->get($item['sku']);
            $product->setPrice($item['price']);
            $quote->addProduct(
                $product,
                intval($item['quantity'])
            );
        }
 
        //Set Address to quote
        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
     
        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
       
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $shippingQuoteRate = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate');
        $shippingRateCarrier = 'freeshipping';
        $shippingRateCarrierTitle = 'Freeshipping';
        $shippingRateCode = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
        $shippingRateMethod = 'freeshipping';
        $shippingRatePrice = '0';
        $shippingRateMethodTitle = 'Free shipping';
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingQuoteRate->setCarrier($shippingRateCarrier);
        $shippingQuoteRate->setCarrierTitle($shippingRateCarrierTitle);
        $shippingQuoteRate->setCode($shippingRateCode);
        $shippingQuoteRate->setMethod($shippingRateMethod);
        $shippingQuoteRate->setPrice($shippingRatePrice);
        $shippingQuoteRate->setMethodTitle($shippingRateMethodTitle);
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(false)
                        ->collectShippingRates()
                        ->setShippingMethod($shippingRateCode); //shipping method
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addShippingRate($shippingQuoteRate);



        $quote->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery'); //payment method
        
        $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory
        $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready
       
        // Set Sales Order Payment
        $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'cashondelivery']);
 
        // Collect Totals & Save Quote
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
        
        $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
        
        $order->setEmailSent(0);
        $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
        if($order->getEntityId()){
            $result=['success' => true, 'message' =>'BuyFaceMask Order processed successfully','order_id'=>  $increment_id];
        }else{
            $result=['success'=>false,'msg'=>'Unable to create order'];
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $region
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getRegionCode(string $region): array
    {
        $regionCode = $this->collectionFactory->create()
            ->addRegionNameFilter($region)
            ->getFirstItem()
            ->toArray();
        return $regionCode;
    }
```

Comment: u need answer or you posted already answer??

Comment: Already posted answer which will help someone.